# What is jQuery(document) vs. $(document)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't get what jQuery(document) is here.  I thought you always used $(document)

see here in his examples: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Comment: I explained this in your old question that you deleted!!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no difference. $ is shorthand for jQuery. Sometimes $ is disabled as it may conflict with other Javascript libraries you are using. It is otherwise identical.

Answer (score 10):

jQuery uses $(). Prototype uses $(). AFAIK Mootools uses $(). If that was the end of it, it would be impossible to use any combination of the three. So responsible frameworks provide a way to disable $() to avoid conflicts and use something else instead. In jQuery's case, that's jQuery().

jQuery() is recommended over $() for use in jQuery plugins, so they keep functioning if you do  disable $().

Answer (score 5):

It's like `<?` versus `<?php`: one is a shorthand version that may be vulnerable to conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

The $ is just a shortcut for JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is just the long-hand way of invoking jQuery.  You might want to do this if you are using it in noConflict mode or internally in a plugin to make sure you are using jQuery's $ function instead of another framework's.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(document) and  $(document) both are alternative