# What is the difference between these jQuery ready functions?

Tags: jquery

what is difference between

```
$(function(){

});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

});
```

Comment: none. or at least it says so in the manual.

Comment: You can read the first as "call a function called $ and hand it the defined function to execute". $ there referes to jQuery, which will execute the function you gave it when it is ready. The second would read as "make a jQuery object from document and attach a eventlistener to it that executes the function you gave it when it is triggered by the ready event".

Comment: See my answer below: IE9 treats them differently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is jQuery(document) vs. $(document)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058463/what-is-jquerydocument-vs-document)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[Nothing whatsoever.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)

> This function behaves just like
>   $(document).ready(), in that it should
>   be used to wrap other $()

You can see this in the [source code](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js):

```
rootjQuery = jQuery(document);

...

} else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {
    return rootjQuery.ready( selector );
}
```

Comment: There is a difference, $(function(){}) is less readable (to my brain at least).

Comment: Agree with Rosdi - one is slighty more expressive about what it's actually doing, one is slightly more terse.  I prefer the expressive version, thought it's ever so slightly less performant: http://jsperf.com/ready-callback-function-vs-document-ready-function/4

Comment: Also in agreement with an observation: it is that lack of expressiveness in the shorthand version that causes this to be such a popular question.

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, only the `$(function() {})` syntax is recommended; the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated. See https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I do not agree, there is a difference.  I tried the exact same function with and without `(document).ready` in front of function and with, async loaded the function variable correctly.  Without, only loaded initial values of variable, without ever giving new async values.  It seems to affect timing, at least on `opera`

Answer (score 16):

```
} else if (jQuery.isFunction(selector)) {
    return rootjQuery.ready(selector);
}
```

From the [source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.5&fn=jQuery.fn.init)

Calling `$(document).ready(selector)` saves a few if statements.

Although jQuery does cache `$(document)` internally that might make `$(f)` faster.

[Benchmarked](http://jsperf.com/ready-vs-jquery)

Comment: If we're talking **that** level of micro-optimisation, you might want to consider the extra 11 bytes needed to transfer the explicit version...

Comment: @lonesomeday Well its only 9 bytes. `$(d).ready(f)` vs `$(f)`

Comment: True, but please be aware that my above comment is meant somewhat humourously!

Comment: @Raynos But then you need to put `var d = document;` at the top or put it inside `(function(d) {` and `})(document);`. :P

Comment: @Nyuszika7H any minified code already has `d = document, w = window`

Comment: @raynos: i forgot to thank u, which i should have done few  days back. cant accept your answer as it has been merged with another one. But real good work thanx.

Answer (score 10):

Both are equivalent, the first is a shorthand form.

Comment: Are you sure? Does the first one wait for the DOM to load?

Comment: Cool, just wanted to make sure. +1

Answer (score 7):

$(function(){}) is a short cut for the dom ready

A function passed as an argument to the jQuery constructor is bound to the document ready event.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you read [this](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). As you can see

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> `$(document).ready(handler)`
>
> `$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)`
>
> `$(handler)`

So it's up to you and to what you prefer.

Comment: `$().ready()` won't work in jQuery 1.4+. `$()` returns an empty selection rather than the document in these circumstances.

Comment: @lonesomeday That's why there's a **(this is not recommended)** in front of it.

Answer (score 7):

The two are exactly equivalent: use whichever form you like.

That said, I personally *always* use the expanded form `$(document).ready(function(){});` for the simple reason that it is completely obvious what the code is doing.  The approximate idea is that of "self-documenting code".  Anyone coming to the code later on will immediately see that the code is to be run on the `document`'s `ready` event.  With the short-hand form, you have to rely upon the reader of your code understanding the meaning.

Answer (score 6):

We have run into situations where IE9 does not run functions within $(function() {}); in the same manner or timing as $(document).ready(function(){});

The issue reared its head for us specifically in reading information out of a query string and processing and displaying that information on the screen, or using it to process a form. IE9 would process the information once it was cached with $(function(), and a user refreshed the page. But on first run, nothing worked right. However, once we switching from $(function(){}); to $(document).ready(), the issue was fixed. We changed NOTHING else.

I so look forward to the day I don't have to test for IE9 and lower.

Comment: document.ready is not connected to the same "native" event for all browsers... you can get one of these: [document.DOMContentLoaded] or [window.load] or [document.onreadystatechange].  I suppose that's the reason why you get a different action in IE, I suppose (without verification) that the $(document).ready(...) is not connected to the same native DOM event than $(function(){})

Comment: I experienced this on `opera` as well.  I have upvoted your answer because I had the exact same issue. (using jquery 3.5)

Answer (score 5):

They're effectively the same. No difference.

---

This is the native way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // code
});
```

And this is a shorthand for the previous.

```
$(function() {
    // code
});
```

[jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L168-172)

Comment: There is a comment on this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975093/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-document - that the use of the shorthand can lead to `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function` errors occasionally.

Comment: @crmpicco Except that thread mentions `$(document)`, so you probably mean the `$` shorthand for `jQuery`.

Answer (score 2):

I use `$(function() {});` because it's shorter. As far as I know there is no difference between the two ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery recommends to use `$( fn )`.

> `$(document).ready(function() {});` or `$(document).on("ready", fn);`
> will cause the function to be called when the document is ready, but
> only if it is attached before the browser fires its own
> DOMContentLoaded event. That makes it unreliable for many uses,
> particularly ones where jQuery or its plugins are loaded
> asynchronously after page load.

For more info, please look into [jquery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/main/warnings.md#jqmigrate-ready-event-is-deprecated)