# $(document).ready(function() VS $(function(){

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is difference of  $(function(){ }); and $(document).ready(function() {  }) ;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-difference-of-function-and-document-readyfunction)

What are the differences between `$(document).ready(function(){})` vs `$(function(){})`
and should I write it in the `$` form or the new `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ })` way?

If I have google api loaded is `google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {` a better way? or is it the same thing?

I've also seen people use `$(function($){})`

Can somebody help me, I'm lost. I bugs me when I don't know the code I write. I guess I should read through the library. Are the all being defined as the same thing?

Comment: exact duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-difference-of-function-and-document-readyfunction

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The two ways are equivalent, I personally prefer the second, `$(function() {});` it's just a [shortcut](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/core.js#L152) for document ready.

About the `new jQuery(document)...` construct, you don't really need to use the `new` operator, jQuery will use it internally if you don't.

The argument that the `ready` handler function receives, is the jQuery object itself.

That's quite useful where you have to run jQuery in compatibility mode with other libraries, for example:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  // use $ here
});
```

The `$` argument inside the callback will refer to the jQuery object, outside that function it might refer to another library like PrototypeJS.

Comment: I think he meant new as 'the new way' JQuery(document)...

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, only the `$(function() {})` syntax is recommended; the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated. See https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 34):

- `$(document).ready(function() {});`
- `$(function() {});`

The two statements are actually the exact same. So the second call is just a shortcut for the first.

The `$` notation is again only a shortcut for `jQuery`. If you have loaded jQuery into your website you can use both. Especially if you don't load other JS librarys, which maybe also use the `$` sign. That brings us to your mentioned

```
(function($){
}(jQuery));
```

call. What is done here is to make sure, that within your created function expression the `$` sign references to the `jQuery` object. You're calling that anonymous function (which has $ as parameter) and pass the `jQuery` object in.

Answer (score 3):

I encourage to read some articles that are very useful to understand somethings in jQuery ( and of course in javascript ), this articles explain how to create a jQuery plugin, but reading it you will understand some basic and important things, like closures witch is the meaning in this (function($){}(jQuery)); statement.

http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/jQueryPluginTutorial_Beginner