# Primefaces - Datatable Widget for var ... not available

Tags: javascript, primefaces, datatable, widget

I am using primefaces 4.0 and jsf 2.2 in my Application. I have created a page where a datatable is nested in a tabview. Now when I want to filter the datatable, it keeps loading and doesn't how a result.

After some time i recognized, that javascript throws the following error: **"Widget for var 'test' not available! "**.

I guess this should be the issue, but what's the problem or how can i solve this? Does anyone have an idea?

Best Regards!

Comment: post your code.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: In the absence of posted code it's impossible to say.   However, there are a couple of frequent causes for this sort of message.

Answer (score 6):

I am posting my answer here hopefully can help some people out there.

I have the same problem. My case is I want to perform the default filter for my `<p:dataTable>`, thus, I have to perform the `PF('dtWidgetVar').filter();` script in javascript when page load.

This is my initial attemp:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    PF('dtWidgetVar').filter();
});
```

It looks perfectly fine, but just doesn't work. Until I find the error in Chrome console `Widget for var 'dtWidgetVar' not available!`, and googling it for hours, finally I found [this thread](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1464). Therefore I add a `$(function(){});` to wrap my script as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(function()
    {
        PF('dtWidgetVar').filter();
    });
});
```

BOOM!, finally it works. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528509/document-readyfunction-vs-function) as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-the-difference-between-these-jquery-ready-functions) both stating that the `$(function(){});` and `$(document).ready(function(){});` are actually the same, so I have also no clue why it works. I have also try to only use `$(function(){});` but it doesn't work. Have to use both functions to make it works, at least in my case. But still, I hope this helps some humans! Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Still helpful 2021 in my Environment Liferay 7.1, JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 7.0.14, also thank you for the links you have provided.

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of posted code it's impossible to say.   However, there are a couple of things I can suggest to look for.

1. Check to see if you have a duplicate widget name in your view. 
   Obviously you wouldn't intuit that from the message you got, but I
   recall in the past getting this same message for duplicate widget
   names
2. Check to see if you have a component where you've given the widget var the same name as the ID.   I've read that this is to be avoided.
3. A very common error is to conflate ids and widget names.  That
   is, you are trying to use an ID as a widget var
4. See what in your code is trying to reference "test"
5. I can't confirm this myself, but I've seen other StackOverflow posts that suggest this is a possible error when you have imported two copies of the jQuery library

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced `Widget for var '[widgetVar]' not available` when using `p:ajax update="@all"` inside a `p:commandButton`. I could avoid the issue by putting content to be updated in a `h:panelGroup` which I referenced in `update` and put the element declaring `widgetVar` outside that panel group.