# Preventing a form from submitting with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

This is my simple form:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-vertical" id="template" autocomplete="off" name="template" method="POST" action="http://test.dev/templates">
    ...various inputs and HTML here...
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

This is my JS which doesn't prevent the form from submitting:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        'use strict';

        $("form#template").on('submit.template', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.debug(e.relatedTarget);
            return false;
        });
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

From past experience, this should prevent the form from submitting when `Update` is clicked. Feel like I am missing something painfully obvious. What could be going on here?

jQuery 2.1.1

Comment: How do you debug it? Is the submit handler fired? Maybe you need to just use document ready handler as a wrapper, e.g: `jQuery(function($){...});` FYI, your `return` statement is useless here

Comment: Most likely that script is not executed. Different reasons, but since this is an inline script it might be in conflict with a `Content-Security-Policy` header. That should be shown in the browsers console.

Comment: @j08691 At the end of the code block, after performing several checks, I had planned to use JS to submit the form. The namespace allows me to turn off the submit check the 2nd time around to prevent looping: `$("form#template").off('submit.template').submit();`

Comment: @arkascha No `Content-Security-Policy` notices.

Comment: You made sure it _is_ executed?

Comment: @arkascha Given it never shows as a fired event in Chrome, it appears it isn't being executed. No idea why though.

Comment: Any console errors? Have you tried doing this in a doc ready block to make sure the dom content is loaded before the event is bound?

Comment: @eComEvo You ***have*** to bind event once element added to the DOM, not before. So set event binding once element is available in the DOM, using e.g document ready handler

Comment: @EzraMorse `(function ($) {...}(jQuery));` is the equivalent of that. Also, the JS loads at the end of all other elements on the page.

Comment: I meant to make sure the _binding_ is executed, so the script. Not the handler you define inside the script.

Comment: @eComEvo NO it is not equivalent of document ready handler

Comment: @A.Wolff They are actually equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528509/document-readyfunction-vs-function

Comment: @eComEvo Read your link again and compare it to your code, this is completly different, `$(handler)` != than self invoked function (passing it or not jQuery)

Comment: Your example works here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8k9y1kLs/.

Comment: its working fine. see https://jsfiddle.net/99Ldz45L/

Comment: Well just throw it in a .ready block and see what happens. Itll take you 15 secs.

Comment: @EzraMorse did that in a .ready block and works the same.

Comment: @eComEvo SO is the FORM added dynamically to the DOM? Why don't you post relevant link or online sample where your issue can be checked???

Comment: @A.Wolff The fiddle posted by j08691 is the same as what I'm working with. It's possible some library I'm including somewhere in the general site is mucking the code up because this has always worked before without issue. And no, the form is not dynamically added. It is a static Blade created form. Can't post the entire source here, regrettably.

Comment: @eComEvo Could you try: `jQuery(document).on('submit.template', 'form#template', function(e){...});`?  As a side note, IDs must be unique on document context, just saying it in case of...

Comment: Its very difficult to figure out the issue without the original source, since the provided code has no problem. If I were you, I would bind click events (or even hide() them to start) to the submit button to test if the events are even being bound. That said, I no longer use forms or submit events anyway so Im normally focused on the GUI elements entirely.

Comment: @A.Wolff Nice idea, but unfortunately it didn't resolve it. :( Just tried this little bit of code right before the `.on()` statement to see if the form is even in the DOM `console.log('len: '+$('form#template').length);` and it is in fact not available. Turns out that is because the `id` attr is missing. I can see it when I `view page source`, BUT I can't see the `id` attribute on the form when I do `inspect element`. The discrepancy appears to be the problem.

Comment: @eComEvo So the template engine remove the ID, quite weird indeed... :(  You could still bind event without specifying any ID, this would work

Comment: @A.Wolff It is very strange and not something I could reproduce with a jsFiddle otherwise I'd post it. For instance, I added the following immediately after the closing `</form>` tag and I get an empty result: `<script type="text/javascript">console.debug(document.getElementsByName('template'));</script>` It's as if the form isn't accessible to JS despite being clearly visible on the screen. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Does it remove class and data- attributes as well? You could bind using those alternatively (or none at all if its the only form on the page)

Comment: @EzraMorse The template engine is actually not removing anything. This is happening purely in Chrome. The class tag remains but data tags are also stripped.

Comment: Is the FORM wrapped inside an IFRAME? I added `laravel` & `blade` tags even i'm not sure this is the relevant ones. An 'expert' regarding this template could then have a look at it

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, the form is in an iframe. I'm viewing the iframe contents when I'm looking at this and the JS is loaded within the iframe for this. Same domain.

Comment: So to access it, try: `$(window).on('load', function(){console.log($('iframe").contents().find("form.form-vertical").length);});`

Comment: @A.Wolff Sames result. Doesn't show as existing. I also tried getting specific since it is loaded by jQuery colorbox and did: `console.log('len: ' + $('iframe.cboxIframe').contents().find("form.form-vertical").length);` No dice though.

Comment: You have to try to access it once the IFRAME is loaded, not before. If still not working, i'm out of idea :(

Comment: @A.Wolff Actually, I just tried `$('iframe.cboxIframe').contents().find("form.form-vertical").length` from the Chrome dev console and it shows that it exists. If I do that same code from the JS code block at the bottom of the page, it shows it doesn't exist, which doesn't make sense since the iframe is loaded when the `.ready()` call is made (and this is in that).

Comment: @A.Wolff In any event, thanks to you and the rest for helping me get to this point. This is a very bizarre bug I'm going to have to keep banging my head against. BTW, thanks for pointing out the discrepancy in my understanding with what was posted in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528509/document-readyfunction-vs-function

Answer (score 1):

Ran through all the form names using `.each()` and discovered the form was called `templates` (plural) despite the fact that many reloads ago I changed it to `template`. Something in the template system was in fact caching that part of the code, and clearing the template cache resolved the issue.

All JS now works as it should without modification.

Comment: This topic should probably be closed or deleted given it didn't end up being an actual JS or jQuery issue in the end.