# How to view pie chart within a div in table row using javascripts functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I want to view pie chart within a div. The div is in a data table row.

My requirement is: When I will click on a data table row, the div in the row of the data table will be expanded and a pie chart will be  displayed within the div.

**Here is my pie chart code:**

```
<script>
        $(function () {

            $(document).ready(function () {

                // Build the chart
                $('.container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false,
                        type: 'pie'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            showInLegend: true
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Brands',
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        data: [{
                            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                            y: 56.33
                        }, {
                            name: 'Chrome',
                            y: 24.03,
                            sliced: true,
                            selected: true
                        }, {
                            name: 'Firefox',
                            y: 10.38
                        }, {
                            name: 'Safari',
                            y: 4.77
                        }, {
                            name: 'Opera',
                            y: 0.91
                        }, {
                            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                            y: 0.2
                        }]
                    }]
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

---

**here is my javascript function:**

```
    function format ( d ) {
            // `d` is the original data object for the row
            return '<div class="slider">'+
                '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
                '<tr>'+
                '<td>Full name:</td>'+
                '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '<tr>'+
                '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
                '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '<tr>'+
                '<td colspan="2"><div class="container"></div>sdfdfsdf</td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '</table>'+
                '</div>';
        }
```

---

**Here is my datatable onclick function:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        // Add event listener for opening and closing details
        $('.example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row( tr );

            if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                $('div.slider', row.child()).slideUp( function () {
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                } );
            }
            else {
                // Open this row
                row.child( format(row.data()), 'no-padding' ).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');

                $('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown();
            }
        } );
    } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply initialise the chart when the container is shown? Take all the code within `$(document).ready(function () {` and move it to callable function

```
function initChart() {
 // Build the chart
 $('.container').highcharts({
   chart: {
...
```

and execute that function in your click handler

```
...
else {
  // Open this row
  row.child( format(row.data()), 'no-padding' ).show();
  tr.addClass('shown');
  $('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown();
  initChart();
}
...
```

**PS**: You seem to be a fan of `$(document).ready` and `$(function () {`. First of all [**using both is redundant**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528509/document-readyfunction-vs-function), but you should [**not use `$(document).ready()` at all**](http://modernweb.com/2013/05/06/5-things-you-should-stop-doing-with-jquery/). It is very rare you actually would *need* to wrap anything into a `ready()` or `(function()`, but many people seems to be using this "pattern" unconsciously without any real purpose, also called [**cargo cult programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). The only real outcome of this is the daily pile of questions with people having scope problems.