# Can a function call be hoisted in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code I see the second console.log is called before the one inside the anonymous function.

Is this an example of hoisting? Is it something specific to do with jquery?

```
var test_var = 'original test_var';

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {

      test_var = 'test_var has been altered!';
      console.log("test_var 1");
      console.log(test_var); //displays 'test_var has been altered!'

    });
    console.log("test_var 2");
    console.log(test_var); //displays 'original test_var'
});
```

Comment: No, the second function call is not hoisted or anything. Rather, the "first" function call *inside the callback* is **deferred**. Welcome to the world of asynchrony!

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate of that function wrapping a function in $() behaves similarly to $(document).ready. Hence it's like adding two handers which are essentially queued.

Comment: @Brian Sure this is async, what makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Sorry jumped the gun on that one - is async in the JS sense - maybe not a dupe though.

Comment: @Brian In dupe, the example `// with promises` is exactly what happen here

Comment: Yeah can see some similar ones but doesn't really highlight that is't something that may not be clear when using jquery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528509/document-readyfunction-vs-function might be a more appropriate dupe to link to

Comment: Hahaha... Learn more oop

Comment: If I replace `$(function() {
...});` with `(function() {
...})();` the variable is assigned first in the anonymous function and then is not undefined on the next line. Seems that $() is asynchronous.