# jQuery UI Accordion not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement jQuery UI accordion to collapse my fields when clicked. But it isn't working. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/kyriediculous/pen/MbvJww)

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });
  });
```

Comment: I don't know what you want but if you comment the accordion on `$(function()`, and then put that code after the `for` in the `success` callback, it will work. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbvmBN

Comment: Hey thanks , you should post as reply so I can upvote!

So I didn't need a function after all? just select the #accordion element and apply the method to it? Because the function on top is now an empty function.

I found a little 'bug' though. When I click a link to go outside of my page jQuery UI breaks until a hard refresh.

I should go check a video on jQuery UI maybe, it looked way more simple on the docs. Thanks again !

Comment: Improve formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't catch that the last time, you have a `$(document).ready()` and you have a `$(function()` inside the `$(document).ready()`, they are the same but abbreviated:

[$(document).ready(function() VS $(function(){](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528509/document-readyfunction-vs-function)

And because you are creating the accordion after the elements are created with javascript, you need to call the accordion method because it's new content.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:apiURL,
    dataType:"json",
    async:false,
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      searchTitles=response[1];
      searchDescription=response[2];
      searchLink=response[3];

      for (var i = 0; i<searchTitles.length; i++) {
        $(".results").prepend("<h3>"+searchTitles[i] +"</h3>" + "<div> <p>"+searchDescription[i]+"</p>" + "<a target='blank' class='btn btn-warning'  href='"+searchLink[i]+"'>More</a></div>");
      }

      //After the new content, generate the accordion
       $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true
      });
   }
});
```