# JQuery button not firing and javascript not prompting for ASP.NET SignalR chat application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am trying to create a chat application on my ASP.NET solution between users. With SignalR installed to help with real-time chatting. However the button created using JavaScript is not firing and the browser is not prompting to enter username as it is suppose to.

Below is my code. [Check out the design here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyl4K.png)

C# code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace Synergince
{
    // This is a class to handle the username and message entered by the  username
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcast method to update clients
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Source Code - JavaScript

```
<div class="container">
<input type="text" id="message" />
<input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
<input type="hidden"id="displayname" />
<ul id="discussion">
</ul>
</div>

<!--Script references -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"">
    $(on('click',function () {
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            var Name = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var Msg = $('<div />').text(message).html();

            //add message to the page
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodeMsg + '</li>');
        };

        //get username from user
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter preferred alias:', ''));
        $('#message').focus();

        //start connection
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {

                //call send method on the hub
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());

                //clear textbox
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try binding it specifically to that button and making sure that [the document is ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) before you bind your handler. If the document isn't ready your click handler won't ever become active.

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#sendmessage').on('click', function() {
        console.log('test');
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="test" id="sendmessage"/>
```

Comment: $(.... is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528509/document-readyfunction-vs-function

Comment: Please help me with code to bind the function to the code. I'm relatively new to JavaScript. Your help would go a long way

Comment: @KelvinNkomo Sorry, the code I posted was incorrect. Fixed the snippet. If there are still problems after that let me know what it's doing.

Comment: It's showing an error 404 for hubs and cannot read  property 'client' of undefined. I ran debug on the browser and these are the errors it shows

Comment: Those are problems far beyond the scope of this question. You should try some specific troubleshooting of those problem or start a new topic if you're stuck detailing the troubleshooting steps you've tried.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help