# Selecting element with ID does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
alert($('#myTableHeader1').width());
alert($('#myTableHeader1').outerWidth());
alert($('#myTableHeader1').innerWidth());
```

None of the above works. Even though I have

```
<th id="myTableHeader1" width="12%"> testest</th>
```

I get the error

> null is null or not an object

Comment: @linesomeday yes i have. I have the following in my head tag <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>

Comment: @user On which line is the error?

Comment: Are you sure that an element with id "myTableHeader1" exists on the page?

Comment: Does it work if you run it from a command line in the IEDevToolbar or FireBug?

Comment: @Šime Vidas all of the elert's lines. ive tried them all seerately and whenever i do i get an error on the line that the alert is on

Comment: You've given only a small bit of code. Nothing in the code you provided will cause an error. Please post the actual code that causes the error.

Comment: Show us what the rest of the page looks like. The code above works, it looks like there is something else wrong with the page and not this code. Tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/nVBkB/

Comment: If you're genuinely interested in an answer, you need to provide more information. Since you haven't provided any, I'm voting to close because the question can't be answered in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){ 

    alert(jQuery('#myTableHeader1').width());
    alert(jQuery('#myTableHeader1').outerWidth());
    alert(jQuery('#myTableHeader1').innerWidth());

});
```

Problem is you be running your JavaScript code even before nodes are created. So you may either add JavaScript at the bottom or run your code after dom ready.

Whatever is passed to `jQuery` runs at dom ready

```
jQuery(function(){

    // codes written here runs at dom ready

});
```

**Note** : below written type1 and type2 are same thing

**Type 1**

```
jQuery(function(){

});
```

**Type 2**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 


}) ;
```

[What is the difference between these jQuery ready functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-difference-of-function-and-document-readyfunction)

Comment: You also need an explanation.

Comment: So your telling them to wait till the DOM is ready. Sounds right to me. Alternatively place script at bottom of page.

Comment: @Praveen You are using `jQuery` and `$` interchangeably. No need for that.

Comment: I get the same error even though i put it in the Jquery function. also i tired putting it right at the end of the page

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe it's the callback passed to `jQuery(document).ready();` that fires when the DOM is ready; Not simply passing a function to the `jQuery` object.

Comment: he should be using `jQuery(function($){...});` and *then* `$`.

Comment: @TomcatExodus: Yes, you're wrong. ;o) That's a valid shortcut for `$(document).ready()` (unless an old version of jQuery is used).

Comment: @TomCat, they are same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-difference-of-function-and-document-readyfunction

Comment: **@patrick dw & @Praveen Prasad;** Did not know that, thank you :) *Note: How old is old? `< 1.5`?*

Comment: @Tomcat: I was wrong about the older version. Looks like it's been supported since version 1.0. http://api.jquery.com/jquery#jQuery3

Comment: **@patrick dw**; Ah, I was unfamiliar with the shortcut. I've always used the `.ready()` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to access the elements before they exist in the dom. The way to do this is to listen for the `window.onload`, or `document.ready` events. jQuery makes this very easy as the standard factory method can take a function to automatically bind to the `document.ready` event:

```
jQuery(function($){});
```

This has an added bonus that it can be used to alias `jQuery` to `$` to allow for the compatibility of using `$` while not having to worry about `noConflict`.

```
jQuery(function($){

  alert($('#myTableHeader1').width());
  alert($('#myTableHeader1').outerWidth());
  alert($('#myTableHeader1').innerWidth());

});
```

You would do well to start using `console.log` instead of `alert` as you can use firebug or the built-in console in opera or chrome.

to use console.log you should check that `console` exists:

```
if (window.console)
{
  console.log(
    $('#myTableHeader1').width(),
    $('#myTableHeader1').outerWidth(),
    $('#myTableHeader1').outerWidth()
  );
}
```

This may or may not be the solution you're looking for. To tell you'll need to post the HTML along with the JavaScript. It may be as simple as a misspelling, or bad html syntax.

Comment: Accessing elements before they're in the DOM won't cause the error OP is getting.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have `console` available, this should work.

```
$(document)
    .ready(function(){
        console.log(
            $('#myTableHeader1').width(),
            $('#myTableHeader1').outerWidth(),
            $('#myTableHeader1').outerWidth()
        );
    });
```

Comment: What is the `e` parameter for? You don't get an `event` argument with `.ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

i think jquery wouldn't get your th if it isn't in table

so try this for html :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th id="myTableHeader1" width="12%"> testest</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

and this for your jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert($('#myTableHeader1').width());
alert($('#myTableHeader1').outerWidth());
alert($('#myTableHeader1').innerWidth());
});
```

here is a working example :
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/MBAsfoor/Lg8tG/1/)