# jquery function wrap vs dom ready

Tags: jquery, domready

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between these jQuery ready functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-the-difference-between-these-jquery-ready-functions)

```
$(function(){
    // ... do stuff
});
```

VS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ... do stuff
});
```

I saw the first one in some old code and I assume the two are similar? Is there a benefit to one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) those are equivalent

Answer (score 2):

they are the same exact thing. i started using the 1st method now as it's more shorthand

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, except the first version is just shorthand.