# $(document).ready + setInterval = multiple instances running

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

My web app currently uses this to kick off notifications retrieval in client-side:

```
$(document).ready( getNotifications() );
```

which is great, but i need it to run every XXX seconds, so I've added a setInterval timer at the end of `getNotifications()`, here:

```
function getNotifications() {

    //(do stuff)

    //now repeat every X seconds (10000 = 10s)
    setInterval(getNotifications, 30000);
}
```

problem -- doing this seems to trigger multiple instances of the timer-loop'd function. using an alert() I can see that every timer cycle creates a new instance set to the timer, not an iteration of the same instance as desired.

how can i get a timer/loop for my functionality without multiple instances?

thanks!

Comment: `$(document).ready( getNotifications() );`  <--- that is wrong!

Comment: care to expand? your comment isnt very useful as is.

Comment: That is not an answer...It is a comment. ;)

Comment: You are calling it, not assigning it. And change setInterval with setTimeout and it will work.

Comment: Whenever you have something like `foo(bar())`, `bar` is executed first and its return value is passed to `foo`. Arguments are **always** evaluated before passed to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`.

setInterval keeps firing every X milliseconds, 
setTimeout fires once after x milliseconds

And you do not want the `()` in the `document.ready`. It is calling `getNotifications`, not assigning the reference to it.

```
function getNotifications() {
    window.setTimeout(getNotifications, 30000);
}
$( getNotifications );
```

Comment: ah...yes, of course -- setInterval starts a loop of the timer'd function, each running at the interval... but since im self-referring to the function at the end of itself, i only need to call it on via setTimeout, which runs once, and then when it executes itself, it calls itself again, etc... got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or, how about (keeping the function cleaner by not having the repeat information inside it):

```
function getNotifications() {

    //(do stuff)
}

$(function() { // this is $(document).ready( in a different form, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-the-difference-between-these-jquery-ready-functions

   getNotiifications(); // call it the first time

   setInterval(getNotifications, 30000); // and every 30 seconds afterwards
}
```