# Get the element after appending using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<div>`.I am trying to append another  which contains a  inside.I am trying to call the input tag by id, but am not getting this element! I tried many questions in the stack, but I can't solve this.

Here is the **HTML** code

```
<div id="newContDiv" class="form-group">
  <div id="newDiv"></div>
 </div>
```

**jquery** for appending div and input tag

```
 var v = "<div id = 'coverDiv'><div id='appDiv'><div><input id='panNumId' 
      type='text' name='panImg1' placeholder='Enter your Pancard number'/>
      </div></div>";
  $('#newDiv').append(v);
```

And I am calling the **element** as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       ('#panNumId').click(function () {
        alert("clicked");
      });
});
```

Comment: try with `$(document).on('click','#panNumId',function () {`

Comment: I tried this,but its not working @Carsten

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console `? because it should work

Comment: It works if panNumId is UNIQUE! and instead of $(document).on("click" use  `$("#newDiv").on("click",'.panNumId'` and change to class instead of ID - of course newDiv ALSO has to be unique and loaded with the page

Comment: try with classname as a selector instead of `id`

Comment: @carsten : No,there is no error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your element is dynamically appended, you wont be able to handle a click event like you are doing. You will need to update your click event to:

```
$("#newDiv").on("click", "#panNumId", function(){
    // code goes here
});
```

Like this

```js
$(function() {
  var v = "<div id = 'coverDiv'><div id='appDiv'><div><input id='panNumId' type = 'text'name = 'panImg1'placeholder = 'Enter your Pancard number' / ></div></div > ";
  $('#newDiv').append(v);

  // it will alert the moment you click the textfield
  $('#newDiv').on("click", "#panNumId", function() {
    alert("clicked");
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newContDiv" class="form-group">
  <div id="newDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nop this one is not working here!

Comment: I had tried many ways in stack and event handlers also.

Comment: Yes,sure.But the problem  here is,Iam not getting the #panNumId element to apply this event.

Comment: then it is likely not unique

Comment: I have added a code snippet to demonstrate this working, hope this helps @AMallal . Thanks!

Comment: Its now working fine.It is working with $('body')' finely.Thankyou Ivanov.It helped me very much.

Comment: I tried it using `$(document).ready();` but it didn't work in this situation.Why did `$(function() {}` worked fine?

Comment: @AMallal [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-the-difference-between-these-jquery-ready-functions) is part of your answer. But why did one work and not the other, to be honest I am not sure. Maybe you had a mistake somewhere? maybe something was not being called correctly? If you provide me with your old code that is not working I might take a look, and try to find out why it was not working. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help.Here in my code,I had just replaced `$(document).ready();` with  `$(function)` .That all I have did,and it worked fine. No other changes were made.

Comment: @AMallal can you make a jsFiddle instead? I dont have time to recreate your situation. Sorry. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

Hope this will helps you :)

```js
var v = "<div id = 'coverDiv'><div id='appDiv'><div><input id='panNumId' type='text' name='panImg1' placeholder='Enter your Pancard number'/></div></div>";
$('#newDiv').append(v);
$(document).on('click','#panNumId',function () {
   alert("clicked");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newContDiv" class="form-group">
    <div id="newDiv"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yeah you are right the way you told me.But the problem is,Iam not getting the #panNumId element.

Comment: Why are you not getting? is there any error in your console? Please check it

Comment: No.Iam not getting any error.