# $(function() vs jQuery(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, frontend, jsgrid

I don't know why [jsGrid](http://js-grid.com/) works in `$(function()` ([sample](https://jsfiddle.net/8hw0wcjj/)) but it doesn't work in `jQuery(document).ready` ([sample 2](https://jsfiddle.net/8hw0wcjj/1/))

The error I get in sample 2 is : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_grid' of undefined`

I need to make it work as it is on [sample 2](https://jsfiddle.net/8hw0wcjj/1/) *`jQuery(document).ready`*

Comment: Did you read [What is the difference between these jQuery ready functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2662778/1287812) and the related ones? Please, add your code here instead of a JSfiddle. If the error is not solved with the above, I suggest a title like "jsGrid not working with jQuery(document).ready"

Comment: This is a hoisting problem. Can't put variable declarations in that function below where you try to access them `friends` and `countries`. The `var` will get hoisted but will be undefined at point you try to access it until the assignment is reached. By then you have already passed `undefined` to plugin

Comment: Simple fix might be helper functions for `getFriends()` and `getCountries()` so the data can reside below and keep the business logic at top

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you so much! works now  https://jsfiddle.net/8hw0wcjj/2/

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because `countries` is undefined. In the working case, you define this variable in the global scope. But, in the second sample, you define it after you use this variable to create the grid.