# When, if ever, should you use `jQuery` over `$`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking through some code and noticed:

```
button: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $target = jQuery(e.target);
  var link = $target.attr('href');
```

I was just a little unclear about the line `var $target = jQuery(e.target);`.

Why use `jQuery` here?

Comment: `$target` is just a variable name...it can be anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is jQuery(document) vs. $(document)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058463/what-is-jquerydocument-vs-document)

Comment: If you are looking for $ vs jQuery.. `$` is an alias/shorthand of `jQuery` period

Comment: @SaurabhSharma . . . except if `jQuery.noConflict()` has been called, or if another library on the page has reassigned `$`.

Comment: Maybe there is another framework that also uses the $ ?

Comment: @AKX Ofcourse..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would like to use `jQuery` instead of `$`, when the latter conflicts with a globar variable from another library.

For instance, see this list: [What JavaScript libraries are known to use the global dollar sign: window.$?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4632083/806975)

In that case, jQuery provides the `noConflict()` method, [which](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

> Relinquish jQuery's control of the $ variable.

The documentation also states:

> In jQuery's case, `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`, so all functionality is available without using `$`. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of `$` back to the other library with a call to `$.noConflict()`. Old references of `$` are saved during jQuery initialization; `noConflict()` simply restores them.